# Recover async subprocess return code completed by timeout

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I would like to know if there is a way to recover the return code when the asynchronous process has been completed by a timeout. 
The constraints are that I want to recover this code in another class that is in another python file. In addition, I do not want to block my GUI ...

In my MainView.py, my code this :

```
        if self.comboBox.currentText() == "HASHCAT" :
        self.process = Hashcat(MainWindow.hashcatPath, 100, 3, MainWindow.hashFilePath, MainWindow.dictPath, MainWindow.pathOutFile)
        self.process.run(2)
```

And my Hashcat.py file look like this :

```
    def run(self,timeout):
        def target():

            FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')

            if self.typeAttack == 0 :
                self.subprocess=\
                    subprocess.Popen([self.pathHashcat,"-m",str(self.algoHash),"-a",str(self.typeAttack),self.pathHashFile,self.pathDict,
                                     "-o",self.pathOutFile],
                                stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

            if self.typeAttack == 3 :

                self.subprocess =\
                subprocess.Popen(
                [self.pathHashcat, "-m", str(self.algoHash), "-a", str(self.typeAttack),self.pathHashFile,"-o",self.pathOutFile])
                self.timer.start()
                self.subprocess.wait()
                self.timer.cancel()



        def timer_callback():
            print('Terminating process (timed out)')
            self.subprocess.terminate()

        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=target)
        self.timer = threading.Timer(timeout, timer_callback)
        self.thread.start()
        print(self.timer.isAlive)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling [`terminate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.terminate) just sends the signal to kill the process; you may still have to [`wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) on it before you can get the [`returncode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode); otherwise, it will still be `None`.

However, the `returncode` is unlikely to be all that meaningful. You just killed the process with a `SIGTERM`, so the `returncode` is going to be `-SIGTERM`.

If the problem is just that `terminate` takes too long, or isn't deterministic—well, `SIGTERM` is meant to be something the child process can use for clean shutdown, which can take time—and can even fail to do anything, if the child has a serious bug. If you really want it to go away immediately, you need to send a `SIGKILL` instead. (This is the difference between `kill 12345` and `kill -9 12345` from the terminal.) The way to do that from `subprocess` is to call the [`kill`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.kill) method instead of `terminate`.

The ideal solution is usually to have a double-timeout—e.g., `terminate` after X seconds, then `kill` if another Y seconds have passed without termination. This gives the process a chance to do graceful shutdown whenever possible, but still guarantees deterministic killing after X+Y seconds. But it depends—for some uses of some programs, giving the child an extra Y seconds to hopefully finish is more important than giving it Y seconds to clean up. Or it doesn't make much difference either way, and the single-step `kill` is just simpler to code.

(This is all a different if you're on Windows, but since you're on OS X, that's irrelevant.)

Comment: Thanks form the quick reply. I want to get the signal of the end of the subprocess in an other class file (MainView.py). In order to, not block my python program... I'm under OS X. I don't know if i'm using the best method to timeout the subprocess asyn...

Comment: @BorisElGareh I don't understand your additional requirements. Are you looking for a way to force the program to absolutely positively terminate in a deterministic amount of time, and `terminate` is taking too long? If so, you can use `kill(SIGKILL)` instead of `terminate()` (or, maybe better, do a `terminate` first, then only `kill(SIGKILL)` if that doesn't happen fast enough).

Comment: @BorisElGareh But either way, that doesn't change the fact that you're not going to get a useful `returncode` if you terminated the process; you're just going to get the signal back, negated (because, after all, you never gave the process a chance to do a normal `exit`, so there can't be any useful `returncode`).

Comment: @abarnet 
Thanks for the additional information, I will use the kill () method. Indeed, my goal is to timeout the process if it takes too much time, in my case 60 seconds would suffice. And I want to run a test in my MainView.py file to find out if the process ended properly or when it was timeout by kill() method

Comment: @BorisElGareh OK, then doing `kill` then `wait` to get the retcode will work… although of course you could also just keep track of the fact that you called `kill`.

Comment: @abarnet, how could i get the return code in my MainView.py with non-blocking reading?